# How to know the minimal mesh size of NIntegrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

Sometimes it is necessary to know the discretization mesh size in numerical integration. But since `NIntegrate` is a complicated composition of various algorithms, it appears unclear to me how to extract such information.

In my naive understanding, `NIntegrate` will often adaptively subdivide the integral region, which is then nonuniform. In that case, probably the minimal mesh size used would be what we want.

So can we know the (minimal) mesh size used?
Optional question: is it controllable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `EvaluationMonitor`

```
xi=Reap[NIntegrate[x^2, {x, -1, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]][[2,1]] // Sort
(*{-0.992043, -0.95309, -0.877083, -0.769235, -0.639815, -0.5, \
-0.360185, -0.230765, -0.122917, -0.0469101, -0.00795732, 0.00795732, \
0.0469101, 0.122917, 0.230765, 0.360185, 0.5, 0.639815, 0.769235, \
0.877083, 0.95309, 0.992043}*)
```

which gives the list of meshpoints used by `NIntegrate`

```
Rest[xi]-Most[xi]//Min (* .0389 minimal meshsize *)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It indeed helps. Let's see if any other answer. BTW, what I had in mind is some 2D integral and surely your method can extract the mesh points. But after some trials of `Min`, `Mean`, `Median` or so of `DistanceMatrix` with the zero-diagonal removed, I still couldn't find a good measure of the discretization scale... Usually we get very small `Min` (not sure if representative at all) and big `Mean`, `Median`. Maybe I was too wishful.

Comment: 2D integration gives a triangle mesh. Study the meshquality to possibly  get more insight